# what are sessions_ids (tokens) for and how to use for security reasons?

Tags: php, security, session, token

I'm a little new to security so I was wondering if someone can shine some light.

Correct me if I'm wrong...

Is token just a term used when using session_id?

Also, what exactly am I supposed to use the session_id (or tokens?) for? I know its for security reasons, but am I supposed to give a user a new session_id from when they login?

i.e. : in all my php pages, is it supposed to have

```
if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
 // html body
}
```

so if the user does not have the session token, they don't access the page?

Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: as per your code : they don't access page if they don't have token session id set

Comment: yeah thats what i'm asking, if thats what I'm supposed to do with the session id, or is there more to it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session token - how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009954/session-token-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session ID's are used to identify server-side session information, like a valet key. When a valid ID is passed (via any means) PHP gains access to the data.

Sessions are used often as a means of storing user authentication details. After successfully signing into the site, you can start a session to store some user data so that subsequent page views can decide whether to allow the use of private information.

For example, after login you might have:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true); // avoid trivial session fixation
$_SESSION['valid'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 123; // identify the user
// whatever else you want to add in your session
header('Location: /index.php'); // redirect the user after signing in
```

The `$_SESSION['valid']` is a token that prevents session adoption attacks; by using `session_regenerate_id` this becomes less critical though. Upon subsequent page views, you can write this code to check if a session is valid and a user is signed in:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['valid'])) {
    die("Invalid session");
}
// do stuff with $_SESSION['user_id']
```

Session ID's can be passed in mainly two ways: via cookies (common) or via `$_GET` (less common). How session ID's are passed is determined by .ini settings:

- session.use_cookies (whether to use cookies at all)
- session.use_only_cookies (whether to only allow cookies, not passed via `_GET`)

Read more here: http://sg.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Comment: doesnt explain what a Session Token is though

Comment: @Gordon Read the link you posted; didn't realize the intended meaning of session tokens .. I always think of it as "that thing you need to do because PHP sessions are easily exploitable" :)

Comment: In what case would `$_SESSION['id'] !== session_id()` ever be true?

Comment: @Gumbo probably never ;-) `$_SESSION['id']` could be replaced with any other value and have the existence thereof determine a valid session. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a token as a keycard - usually, you send a login request to the server who returns a new token if your credentials are valid. If you then request data from the server, you just "show" him that token instead of resending the credentials. So a token is used to hide information.

The session id is not necessarily a token (in a strong meaning). It is used to identify a user, but does not say anything about who he is or what kind of access rights he has.

If you, however, store information about the user and its access rights in the session (e.g. `$_SESSION['userId'] = 17; $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;`), the session id becomes a token - sending it to the server identifies the user AND the server can tell from it whether access should be granted or denied. Storing another token in the session does not make any sense, because hiding information that is not send to the client is overkill. You can safely store information about the user in the session and then use the session id as a token "to" that information.