# How to handle Multiple Security Tokens in SESSION and html Forms

Tags: php, security

I want to use the security token as hidden input field in my comment form for security purpose. I know if there is only one form in my webpage, I can do some thing like that

```
$token = sha1(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

I can use this token in my form

```
<form action="comment.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="comment_body" value="" />
</form>
```

and on the receiving end, I can do that

```
if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){ 

   /* Valid Token */

}
```

But I have about 10 forms on a single page So How I can generate multiple tokens and How to handle them on receiving end. And What If a user open multiple pages?

Comment: What is the purpose of this token?

Comment: @Gumbo To Prevent the CSRF Attack.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of microtime and mt_rand which I basically use when dealing with such scenario

```
$tokenLen = 64;

$randomData = mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . microtime(true) . uniqid(mt_rand(), true);

$token =  substr(hash('sha512', $randomData), 0, $tokenLen);
```

Comment: I think, You have not read my question completely. I do not want to know about how to build a secure token, I just want to know that How can I handle multiple tokens.

Comment: You can just store them in separate hidden fields for each form and store them with name appended with form name lets say hidden_form1, hiiden_form2. Then you can easily retrieve them based on which form you submit.

Comment: but the Problem is How I will handle them on the receiving end. I mean a single token can be stored in a `$_SESSION['token']` but How I will store multiple tokens and How I will compare them?

Comment: you can store the value $_SESSION['token'] as an array keeping the key as a hidden field name or form name like array("hidden1"=>token1, "hidden2"=>token2) and so on etc, just an option

Answer (score 0):

To prevent CSRF, [a single session-dependent token does already suffice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10469840/53114).

However, if you want to use a different token for each form, you can associate the token to the form characteristics, e.g., the action URL and method, for example:

```
// issue token
$form = array('method'=>'POST', 'uri'=>'/comment.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['CSRF_TOKENS']["{$form['method']}:{$form['uri']}"])) {
    $_SESSION['CSRF_TOKENS']["{$form['method']}:{$form['uri']}"] = generate_csrf_token();
}
echo '<form method="'.$form['method'].'" action="'.$form['uri'].'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="CSRF_TOKEN" value="'.$_SESSION['CSRF_TOKENS']["{$form['method']}:{$form['uri']}"].'">';


// check token
$form = array('method'=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'uri'=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (isset(${'_'.$form['method']}['CSRF_TOKEN'], $_SESSION['CSRF_TOKENS']["{$form['method']}:{$form['uri']}"]) && ${'_'.$form['method']}['CSRF_TOKEN'] === $_SESSION['CSRF_TOKENS']["{$form['method']}:{$form['uri']}"]) {
    // token valid
} else {
    // token missing or invalid
}
```

Another possible solution is to used [signed CSRF tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2695291/53114). You can add the given example as much additional information besides the user ID as you want to further limit the validity of the token.